# ansible How escape comma while passing as a list

Tags: ansible

I have a play where i need to use a loop to iterate through `items` in it but the problem is the list items are having `,` in a string values such as `ENT0005, bay 11` and `ENT0005, bay 11` which i'm not able to get rid of.

## My play:

```
- name: Create server profile
  oneview_server_profile:
    config: "{{ config }}"
    data:
      serverProfileTemplateName: "{{ server_profile_template }}"
      serverHardwareName: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
        - "ENT0005, bay 11"
        - "ENT0005, bay 12"
      name: "{{ server_profile }}"
```

## My trial:

This does not work as well..

```
      serverHardwareName: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
        - "\(ENT0005, bay 11\)"
        - "\(ENT0005, bay 12\)"
```

Please suggest.

## EDIT:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    config: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ config_file }}"
    contents: "{{lookup('file', config)}}"
    server_profile_template: 'Test_apc_SY 480 Gen10 2 NVMe Application Template 20190601 V1.0'
    server_hardware: "SY 480 Gen9 1"
    #server_hardware_name: "ENT0005, bay 11" "ENT0005, bay 12"
    server_profile: "apc_SY 480 Gen10 2 NVMe Application Template 20190601 V1.0"
    template_name: []
    server_list: []

  tasks:

## Apply the server profile templates

        - name: Create server profile
          oneview_server_profile:
            config: "{{ config }}"
            data:
              serverProfileTemplateName: "{{ server_profile_template }}"
              serverHardwareName: "{{ item }}"
              loop:
                - "ENT0005, bay 11"
                - "ENT0005, bay 12"
              name: "{{ server_profile }}"
            params:
              force: True
          delegate_to: localhost
          register: result
        - debug: msg= "{{ result.msg }}"
        - debug: msg= "{{ result }}"
    
    ...
```

## ERROR

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in 'serverProfile.yml': line 19, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Create server profile\n      ^ here\n"
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please edit your question and show the actual result and the expected one. Please also check your task yaml because the `loop` stanza is not correctly indented (should be at the same level as the module name) and there is a `name` attibute after it that looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: @Zeitounator, Just updated the post, thx for your comment.

Comment: You still have indentation problems. The `loop` attribute is still mis-aligned (see @Zeitounator's comment), and looks as if it may also be at the wrong position w/r/t arguments to the `oneview_server_profile` module (it looks as if the following `name` and `params` attributes are supposed to be module arguments).

Comment: @larsks, just updated  the indentation, yes `name` an `params` are module args and `name` in aligned under `data` whereas `params` under  `oneview_server_profile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how many different ways we can say that the `loop` directive "should be at the same level as the module name". We mean:

```
- name: Create server profile
  oneview_server_profile:
    config: "{{ config }}"
    data:
      serverProfileTemplateName: "{{ server_profile_template }}"
      serverHardwareName: "{{ item }}"
      name: "{{ server_profile }}"
    params:
      force: true
  loop:
    - "ENT0005, bay 11"
    - "ENT0005, bay 12"
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: result
- debug: msg= "{{ result }}"
```

See how `loop` is aligned with `oneview_server_profile`? That means that these are both parameters of the task. Anything indented under `oneview_server_profile` is going to be an argument to the module itself (which doesn't know what to do with the `loop` directive).

Also note that it doesn't make sense to order your `debug` tasks like this:

```
- debug: msg= "{{ result.msg }}"
- debug: msg= "{{ result }}"
```

If `result` doesn't have a `msg` attribute, the first task will fail and you'll never see the contents of the `result` variable. Always order them less specific `->` more specific:

```
- debug: msg= "{{ result }}"
- debug: msg= "{{ result.msg }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer, however i'm still wondering the how the loop ordering is being aligned , when i place the loop under `serverHardwareName` then it fails while keeping it at the end of the block as you did just before `delegate_to` it works, any idea or documentation to know about it ?

Comment: `loop` is an argument to the task, not the `oneview_server_profile` module. That means it needs to either (a) come before the module name or (b) after all the module arguments. In either case, it is a key on the task dictionary so it must be aligned at the same level as the module name. There is lots of good documentation at https://docs.ansible.com/.

Comment: Thanks Larks , got it much appreciated.

Comment: @user294110 At this point you might as well have a look at [Learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) or any other similar quick doc to get the vary basics of what to be careful with in a yaml file, starting with indentation.

Comment: @Zeitounator, thanks a lot for the pointing a link, i will learn out of it.